# the angular default route give empty page rather than going to componant

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

by application contain app component .html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

with router

```
const routes: Routes = [

 {
 path: '',
 component: LandingPageComponent,
 canActivate: [AuthGuard],
 children: [

  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: DashboardComponent,
  },

]
 },
 {
  path: 'login',
  component: LoginComponent
 },
 {
  path: '**',
  redirectTo: 'dashboard'
 }


 ];
```

the landing page code

```
   <!-- side bar menu -->
 <sidebar #sideBar id="sideBar"></sidebar>
   <!-- /side bar menu -->
  <!-- top navigation -->
   <topbar></topbar>
   <!-- /top navigation -->

 <!-- page content -->
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <!-- /page content -->

 <!-- footer content -->
  <bottomfooter></bottomfooter>
   <!-- /footer content -->
```

my guard

```
    @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
    export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
      constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) { }
      canActivate() {
        return this.authService.user.pipe(
          map(user => {
            if (user) return true;

            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
          }));
      }
    }
```

every thing is working fine except the defualt route it suppose direct to the dashboard but it give me empty page with the side and top nav bar

any suggestion how can i solve this problem

Comment: Why do you have 'DashboardComponent' defined two times as within the children? Are you doing any routing inside auth guards?

Comment: yes i do some conditions in guards ... i updated the post adding the guards

Comment: Have to tried commenting this bit in the children array ? {path: '', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: DashboardComponent,}

Comment: yes i did but in vain

Comment: Try adding pathMatch. {
  path: '**',
  redirectTo: 'dashboard',
  pathMatch: 'full'
 }

Comment: the problem was the arrangment of the modules inside the app module which fixed by rearrang again

Comment: Glad you were able to fix it.